# Is there any proof that the speed of gravity is limited?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, speed-of-light

I must warn that though I'm argumenting with black holes I'm **not asking how does gravity escape the black hole!**. I want to know if the absolute speed of gravity waves were **proven** bu an experiment.

We know that anything with $v\le c$ cannot escape the event horizon of a black hole. But the gravity itself seems quite unaffected by itself. There can be the explanation that the gravity does **not** interact with itself - but no matter what, in this case it directly violates the rule that no information can leave the black hole.
This brings me to he question itself - I'm having serious doubts that the speed limit was proven for the gravity.

I've found [nice explanation](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=257081) of the problem with the black hole though:

> As I understand it, to the outside observer the black hole takes an infinite time to form, although in its own frame, the black hole forms right away. In any case, the gravity felt by the outside observer is that of the object becoming a black hole.

Comment: Dear Tomáši, it's not quite true that it takes an infinite time for the black hole to form. See e.g. http://motls.blogspot.com/2008/11/why-can-anything-ever-fall-into-black.html?m=1 for a related discussion...

Comment: There's a [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_gravity#Possible_experimental_measurements) on this.

Comment: @LubošMotl Unfortunately I must admit that reading the article didn't make me much smarter. Can this be explained simply enough for me? :)